# java.lang.VerifyError with NotificationChannel on Android 8.1

Tags: android-notifications, smali

I am having difficulties in upgrade of an app from API v23 to API v26. I don't have java sources of that app - only smali code.
The app itself is using background services (IntentService class) and I noticed that Android 8+ doesn't allow background execution in most of the cases.  The workaround seems to be to use Foreground Service, which requires execution of startForeground from the service and a Notification as an argument.  Apparently it is not enough just to create a Notification like this:

```java
startForeground(1,new Notification());
```

Android will through an exception about invalid channel.  So I have to create channel.  I tried to do so, but I am having another exception (Android x86 8.1 RC2):

```
08-07 00:39:36.203  9267  9267 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class x.x.x.x: void x.x.x.x.onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent) failed to verify: void x.x.x.x.onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent): [0x2F] 'this' argument 'Precise Reference: android.app.NotificationChannel' not instance of 'Reference: android.app.Service' (declaration of 'x.x.x.x' appears in /data/app/x.x.x.x-qT_QaPGZdwrxOYueAwU_nQ==/base.apk)
08-07 00:39:36.204  2475  4983
```

I wonder what might be the problem.  Did I transfer smali code incorrectly?  Or should I tweak AndroidManifest.xml somehow (i speficified target api v26, BTW)?

Here is a code that I compiled as smali and transfered:

```java
package myservice;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyTestService extends IntentService {
    public MyTestService() {
        super("test-service");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String NEED_FOREGROUND_KEY = "NEED_FOREGROUND_KEY";
                        if ( intent.getBooleanExtra(NEED_FOREGROUND_KEY, false) ) {
                                        //startForeground(1,new Notification());

                                        String CHANNEL_ID = "default";
                                        String channelName = "default";
                                        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
                                        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

          Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                                                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                                                .build();
                                        startForeground(1, notification);

                                        Log.d("javasrv:service", "*** Running as a foreground service ***");
                        }
                        //Log.d("javasrv:service", "Hello!");
    }
}
```

Here is how the final smali code looks like:

```
# virtual methods
.method protected onHandleIntent(Landroid/content/Intent;)V
    .locals 17

#
# (MOD]
#
    move-object/from16 v4, p0

    move-object/from16 v5, p1

    const/4 v3, 0x0

    const-string v0, "NEED_FOREGROUND_KEY"

    invoke-virtual {v5, v0, v3}, Landroid/content/Intent;->getBooleanExtra(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z

    move-result v0

    if-eqz v0, :cond_aaa0

    const-string v1, "default"

    const-string v0, "default"

    new-instance v2, Landroid/app/NotificationChannel;

    invoke-direct {v2, v1, v0, v3}, Landroid/app/NotificationChannel;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)V

    const-string v0, "notification"

    invoke-virtual {v4, v0}, Lx/x/x/x;->getSystemService(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

    move-result-object v0

    check-cast v0, Landroid/app/NotificationManager;

    invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Landroid/app/NotificationManager;->createNotificationChannel(Landroid/app/NotificationChannel;)V

    new-instance v0, Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;

    invoke-direct {v0, v4}, Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;->setChannelId(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;->build()Landroid/app/Notification;

    move-result-object v0

    const/4 v1, 0x1

    invoke-virtual {v2, v0, v1}, Lx/x/x/x;->startForeground(ILandroid/app/Notification;)V

    :cond_aaa0
#
# [/MOD]
#
```

The only thing I've done is first two commands of transfer of values of p0 & p1 into respective variables and a replace of p0 & p1 on the rest of the code by these variables.

Answer (score 0):

But of course!
I messed up the smali code:

```
invoke-virtual {v2, v0, v1}, Lx/x/x/x;->startForeground(ILandroid/app/Notification;)V
```

I left it from the old code w/o notification channel.  Of course I should use v4, which contains *this* object.

Facepalm